# Why resizing windows in Ubuntu 16.04 is too slow?

Tags: unity, 16.04, gui

I have noticed lately that whenever i try to resize any window in Ubuntu 16.04, i get very slow performance.

I have checked my graphic driver and everything in my GUI seems to work perfectly except for this.

Thanks

Comment: Am i the only one facing this issue ?!

Comment: What video hardware, graphics driver, and desktop are you using?

Comment: I am using unity desktop, and my graphic driver is nvidia binary driver - version 361.42 (propriety, tested)

Comment: From the nvidia-settings GUI, under the GPU-0 what do your total dedicated memory and used memory show? mine show 2047M/210M and I have no size speed problems (same drver).

Comment: My total dedicated memory is 4095 and used memory is 407. this issue also appear on a fresh install of Ubuntu, so i am sure i haven't done anything wrong with the system.

Comment: @OsamaAhmaro I have same problem with the same driver. My card is GeForce GTX650

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your BIOS/UEFI Settings for video options.  I have selected discrete only, instead of Integrated or Optimized, so only the Nvidia hardware is used (Quaddro 1000).  I get a little screen tearing, which I don't see when using the nouveau driver, but I use Nvidia for thermal considerations.  Even under the nouveau driver, performance was good.  Which release of Ubuntu are you using?  I've seen bad window movement in the past, but not with my current setup, which seems similar to yours.